# .NET cache providers that support streaming?

Tags: c#, caching, memcached, appfabric

Does anyone know any cache providers for .NET that support streaming data directly in/out by key, rather than serializing/deserializing objects?

I was rather hoping AppFabric (Velocity) would, but it only appears to deal with objects like the built-in ASP.NET cache.

Comment: What distinction are you trying to make between streaming and serializing?  To stream an object you will need to convert it to bytes anyway.

Comment: Can you clarify the type of usage you would like to see here?

Comment: Sorry - my use case is for raw binary data - byte arrays of financial data - that come streaming from a very slow back-end system, to hundreds of users through a WCF service.

Each buffer can be up to 100MB+ (although usually less than 10MB), so we want to stream them to clients rather than buffering the whole thing at once in memory.

A fast distributed file system could also work here - we looked at Hadoop HDFS but it seems not very well supported under Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NCache Enterprise](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/index.html#et) is the only .NET cache provider I can find that supports streaming:

```
// Insert
using (var cacheStream = cache.GetCacheStream("mykey", StreamMode.Write))
    cacheStream.Write(...);

// Retrieve
using (var cacheStream = cache.GetCacheStream("mykey", StreamMode.Read))
    cacheStream.Read(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily implement this yourself in your WCF service (I assumed that is what you wanted to do.)

Either have the clients poll for new data periodically, or implement the [callback pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) to send new data to the subscribed clients as it arrives, depending on what keys they are subscribed too.

Otherwise you could have each client connect to your service via a socket, and repeat the data you receive from the source to these sockets, plus keep the data yourself so if a new client connects, you can send the whole lot of data to them, in their easy to digest chunks.

Plus you can design the application to not care what data it is streaming, just that it is streaming a blob, and use it for other applications in the future.

Edit: You could always use the [streaming transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) build into WCF to stream to your users, but would still not solve your problem retriving data from the source unless they were to implement it too.

Comment: Our service already uses WCF streaming transport of blobs to clients. We just need to put some cache provider behind it, that also supports streams.